# Extract typelib guid from COM-visible .net dll

Tags: .net, vb.net, com, vb6, typelib

I wrote several COM-visible .NET DLLs to make them accessible from VB6 projects, and also a tool who displays some infos like TypeLib GUIDs (LIBIDs). I'm trying right now to extract LIBIDs from these DLLs.

I can read TLB files generated by RegAsm (which are essentials, if I understood, to use them) whith the tool as if it were a COM DLL, by this piece of code (VB.NET) :

```
' Binpath can be a tlb file or a COM DLL.'
reglib = New TLI.TLIApplication
tlb = reglib.TypeLibInfoFromFile(binpath)
guid =  tlb.GUID
```

I cannot read the LIBID directly from the COM-Visible .NET DLL... If I understand, this value is not embedded in the dll, but generated by RegAsm. Is this GUID predictable ?

Comment: Look at your project's Properties\AssemblyInfo.vb file, you can't miss it.

Comment: Thanks. You're talking about Assembly GUID ? Actually I'm looking for LIBID GUID, and sounds like they're are different... Moreover, I'm looking for a way to extract it from the dll if possible...

Comment: Read the comment on that attribute, it is quite explicit about what it is used for.  "Extracting" simply takes Assembly.GetCustomAttributes() to obtain the [Guid] attribute.  This is the job that Tlbexp.exe does, doing it yourself doesn't generally make a lot of sense.  But of course it would always be wise to compare what it does with what your code is doing.  After which you'll no doubt be convinced that this is indeed the attribute you are looking for.

Comment: I just deleted my comment, and turned it into a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39391655/getting-two-different-guids-for-an-assembly).