# Getting two different GUIDs for an Assembly

Tags: .net, guid

Let this piece of code :

```
Dim GUID as String
Dim GUID2 as String
GUID  = "{" & _
          System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(binpath). _
            GetCustomAttributes _
              (GetType(Runtime.InteropServices.GuidAttribute), _
               True)(0).Value.ToString.ToUpper & "}"
GUID2 = "{" & _
          Reflection.AssemblyName. _
            GetAssemblyName(binpath).GetType.GUI‌D.ToString() & "}"
```

Why `GUID` and `GUID2` aren't the same value ?

Edit : here, binpath leads to a (COM Visible) .NET dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetAssemblyName(binpath).GetType.GUI‌D.ToString()` [returns the GUID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.guid(v=vs.110).aspx) for the **`Type`**; it's the same as `typeof(AssemblyName).GUID` (in C#; I don't know how to write that in VB.NET), which is probably not what you wanted.

Comment: If I understood correctly, `GetAssemblyName(binpath).GetType.GUI‌D.ToString()` will always return the same GUID, the one linking to AssemblyName type.